# Show that CPA-security implies security against plaintext recovery

Tags: provable-security, chosen-plaintext-attack, key-recovery

Consider the following experiment:

1. $k = Gen(1^n)$
2. $m \stackrel{u}{\in} \{0,1\}^{l(n)}$
3. $c = Enc_k(m)$
4. $m' = B(1^n,c)$

Define the winning event as $m' = m$. I would like to show that if the encryption scheme $Enc$ is CPA-secure thn every PPT-algorithm $B$ can only succeed with negligible probability in the above experiment.

**Proposal**

This is the solution I have come up myself with:

[image]

Comment: Could be useful to think of it this way: Assume the adversary can recover the plaintext with non-negligible probability using $B$. What would this say about the CPA-Security of the scheme?

Comment: The last probability doesn't need to be $2^{-l(n)}$. It could be anything as long as the sun of probabilities of $B$ over the set of messages is 1. The key is, no matter that value, it's negligible and so your new distinguished $A$ as a non negligible advantage in the CAP game.

Comment: An alternative could be to consider the *ind-rch* game where the attacks sends one message instead of 2 in the case of ind-cpa. Then the challenger selects the bit $b$ uniformly and if m is 0, it encrypts the message, otherwise the challenger selects another message of the same length at random and encrypts it.  This might be easier since you only have one $m$ to 'worry' about. Finally, you can show that you can  construct an efficient efficient attacker for ind-cpa from an attacker for ind-rch with the same advantage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is almost correct. Just don't forget to consider the following two cases: 1) $m_0$ and $m_1$ may be the same, then $A$ will have to guess the secret bit $b$ blindly; 2) $B$ may return the other message, e.g., $B$ happens to return $m_1$ when given $E_k(m_0)$, then $A$'s output will be wrong. Note that 1) and 2) occur with only negligible probabilities.